# Why is function not executed when webpage is opened in browser?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, browser, prompt

I am trying to create a function that loops infinitely until user inputs that they would like to exit. Every time I open up the webpage in the browser, however, no prompt box appears and the `infiniteLoop()` function does not execute. Why is the `infiniteLoop()` function not being called?

```
function infiniteLoop() {
    i= 0;
    var begin= prompt("Shall we begin?");
    if (begin == "Yes") {
        var tryAgain= prompt("Exit loop?");
        if (tryAgain != "Yes") {
            infiniteLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call a function infiniteLoop() on load.

Comment: The code is not working because you have defined the function but not called it anywhere outside its definition. That's why when you call the function `infiniteLoop()` anywhere outside the definition, it will start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function in the window onload event.

```
window.onload = function(){
     infiniteLoop();
}
```

or, if you're using jquery

```
$(function() {
    infiniteLoop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The prompt box doesn't appear because you didn't call the function when your web page loads.

Add ***infiniteLoop()*** after you declare your function.

e.g.

```
function infiniteLoop() {
    i= 0;
    var begin= prompt("Shall we begin?");
    if (begin == "Yes") {
        while (i < 5) {
            var tryAgain= prompt("Are you sure?");
            if (tryAgain == "Yes") {
                i++;
            }
            else {
                infiniteLoop();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        infiniteLoop();
    }
}
// Initial call
infiniteLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

IT WORKS, write 5 times "Yes"(case sensitive) it finishes, otherwise it works infinitely, and do not forget to call **infiniteLoop()**

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up and working

```
(function infiniteLoop() {
  var begin = prompt("Shall we begin?");

  if (begin === "Yes") {
    var i= 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      var tryAgain = prompt("Are you sure?");
      if (tryAgain === "Yes") {
        i++;
      }

      else {
        infiniteLoop();
      }
    }
  }

  else {
    infiniteLoop();
  }
})()
```